# make several Dim new for an object

Tags: arrays, class, vb.net

I a class that is called in program to do some calculation.  Now it got necessary to call this class multiple times because of I need this calculation for all database table row members. I have `For... Next` but its not working correct and every time it returns just last  call calculated amount to database the part of code is this:

```
For j As Integer = 0 To symbols.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim spread As Double
    Dim digits As Integer = symbols.Rows(j)("Digits")
    Dim symbolgroupconditionrow = symbolsgroupcondition.Select("ID = '" & symbols.Rows(j)("SymbolGroupID") & "'")
    Select Case digits
        Case 0
            spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 1)
        Case 1
            spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 0.1)
        Case 2
            spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 0.01)
        Case 3
            spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 0.001)
        Case 4
            spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 0.0001)
        Case 5
            spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 0.00001)
    End Select
    Dim qclient As New Quotereader
    qclient.GetWord("iqlink", symbols.Rows(j)("Symbol"), "last", spread)
Next j
```

the object `Quotereader` is in a class file that I have import it before, now my question is that is there any way to "Dim new" an object in several names for example :

```
Dim qclient(10) As New Quotereader
For I = 0 to 9
    qclient(I).GetWord("iqlink", symbols.Rows(j)("Symbol"), "last", spread)
Next I
```

or any other ways ?

Comment: I have tested to make Dim qclient As New Quotereader before for loop but its not working too

Comment: That Case statement screams "refactor" to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the code as below and it has been ok .

```
        Dim   j As Integer = 0 

            Dim qclient = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Select((Function(i) New Quotereader))
            For Each cl As Quotereader In qclient
                Dim spread As Double



                Dim digits As Integer = symbols.Rows(j)("Digits")


                Dim symbolgroupconditionrow = symbolsgroupcondition.Select("ID = '" & symbols.Rows(j)("SymbolGroupID") & "'")


                Select Case digits
                    Case 0


                        spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 1)

                    Case 1

                        spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 0.1)
                    Case 2


                        spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 0.01)


                    Case 3
                        spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 0.001)

                    Case 4
                        spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 0.0001)

                    Case 5
                        spread = ((symbols.Rows(j)("Spread") + symbolgroupconditionrow(0)("SpreadTopup")) * 0.00001)

                End Select






                cl.GetWord("iqlink", symbols.Rows(j)("Symbol") + ".FXCM", "last", spread)
                j = j + 1
            Next
```

Thanks jcwrequests for his kind advise .

Answer (score 1):

I think if I understand the question correctly how do you initialize 10 new objects into that array?  If that is the case you can use linq.

```
Dim qclient = Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToList().Select(fuhction(i) New QuoteReader()).ToArray()
```

What this does is create a list of 11 integers from 0 to 10, create an instance of QuoteReader for each number in the list then returns an array of QuoteReaders.  I am not sure if that is what you are after but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks , I get your advise and changed the code to below and its now ok , thanks again